# Is it possible to validate value against array value of different model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model called `Donation`, that `belongs_to User`.

Have also a `RemoteAccount` model, with method `:donation_amounts`, that returns an array of numbers it can accept (E.g. `[10, 25, 50, 100, 250, 500]`)

For every `RemoteAccount` this array is different.

I need to make sure that Donation, submitted to that User is within values his account can accept.

Is that possible?

Logic is something like this:

```
validates :amount, inclusion: { in: self.user.remote_account.donation_amounts }
```

(obviously it doesn't work, but you get the idea)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried anything like [Custom Validator](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#performing-custom-validations) ? I think it is exactly what you need.

```
class MyValidator < ActiveModel::Validator
  def validate(record)
    unless record.name.starts_with? 'X'
      record.errors[:name] << 'Need a name starting with X please!'
    end
  end
end

class Person
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  validates_with MyValidator
end
```

Comment: I did two other ways guys suggested, but this was the best one (since this is the only way that keeps other Shoulda tests pass).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom validator inside your model class like this:

```
validate :check_values

def check_values
  # Here you do the custom check returning true or false
end
```

More information here: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-validators

Answer (score 0):

you can use proc to do this.

```
validates :amount, inclusion: { in: proc { |record| record.user.remote_account.donation_amounts } }
```